# Why is my formula not working for a pick list value?

Tags: formula, picklist

I am trying to make a field populate with a formula based on a selection in a picklist value. can you please check my formula?

```
CASE(FedCapture__Our_Role__c,

"Prime",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))
)

"Subcontractor",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))
)

"JV - Managing Partner",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))
)

"JV - Minority Partner",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))
))
```

Comment: use ISPICKVAL()

Comment: @SantanuBoral `ISPICKVAL()` isn't required if `FedCapture__Our_Role__c` is the picklist. Read the last tip included in the description of Case in [the formula function documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US).

Comment: Right now, you're getting the error at `"Subcontractor"`, because the right-paren immediately before that is closing your `CASE()`. It looks like you want to make a second comparison after testing is `FedCapture__Our_Role__c` is "Prime", "Subcontractor", etc..., but to help you build that, we'll need additional information. Please [edit] your question to include more details about the conditions where you want to use `Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c` vs when you want to use `Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * 100 * Calculated_PWIN__c` (or `G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c` later on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `CASE()` formula is this:

```
CASE(
    field to compare,
    test_value_1, result_1,
    test_value_2, result_2,
    ...
    test_value_n, result_n,
    default_result
 )
```

If we use this, and apply it to your provided formula...

```
CASE(
    FedCapture__Our_Role__c,
    'Prime', Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c),
    Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))
),
'Subcontractor', ...
```

So by the time we get to testing for your second picklist value, you've already exited the `CASE()` function. Salesforce has no idea what to do with your formula after that point.

By looking at your attempted formula, I can guess that you want to perform an additional test for each picklist value to determine which calculation (one of two) that you want to perform.

You haven't included enough information in your question for me to give an exact formula, but the general version would look something like this:

```
CASE(
    FedCapture__Our_Role__c,
    "Prime", IF(<some field> = <some value>, Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * (Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))),
    "Subcontractor",IF(<some field> = <some value>, Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))),
    "JV - Managing Partner", IF(<some field> = <some value>, Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))),
    "JV - Minority Partner",IF(<some field> = <some value>, Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c)))
)
```

Notice how I've added an `IF()` into things here. If you want to perform one of two calculations, that's what you'll need to do. The information about which picklist value is chosen for a given record isn't enough.

You could also simplify the formula a little bit (removing extraneous parenthesis, getting rid of a few non-required field references)

```
CASE(
    FedCapture__Our_Role__c,
    "Prime", Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c * IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1, 100),
    "Subcontractor",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c * IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1, 100),
    "JV - Managing Partner", Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  *  Calculated_PWIN__c * IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1 ,  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c),
    "JV - Minority Partner",Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  *  Calculated_PWIN__c * IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1 ,  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c)
)
```

+edit: 
The above formula could be simplified further still. Since `Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  *  Calculated_PWIN__c` is common to all picklist values, we can take that out of the `CASE()` entirely

```
Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  *  Calculated_PWIN__c *
CASE(
    FedCapture__Our_Role__c,
    "Prime", IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1, 100),
    "Subcontractor", IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1, 100),
    "JV - Managing Partner", IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1 ,  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c),
    "JV - Minority Partner", IF(<some field> = <some value>, 1 ,  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c)
 )
```

Comment: Thank you Derek i realized that i actually didnt need to make it so complicated thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it to work thanks!

```
    CASE(FedCapture__Our_Role__c,
"Prime", Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c,
"Subcontractor", Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c,
"JV - Managing Partner", Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * Calculated_PWIN__c G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c, NULL)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume Fed_Capture_Our_Role__c is the picklist. So that would play out like this:

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "Prime"), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c)),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "Subcontractor"), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c)),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "JV - Managing Partner"), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))),
IF(
ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "JV - Minority Partner"), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c), Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((  G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c) * (Calculated_PWIN__c)),
""))))
```

I think the () line up it got a little confusing at the end of the line, but you get the idea.

EDIT:

You could use CASE but not in the way you currently have this setup. CASE works as CASE(expression, value, result, else_result)

Looking at your first lines you have

expression: FedCapture__Our_Role__c
value: "Prime"
result: Total_Contract_Value_USD__c  * ( Calculated_PWIN__c)
else: Total_Contract_Value_USD__c * ((100) * (Calculated_PWIN__c))

then you close it. Which would work for the one line but you continue the pattern without a new CASE(expression. So if you want to go down that path you need to remove your else result or put more case(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, in there.

Comment: If you use the `CASE()` function, you don't need all of those `IF()` and `ISPICKVAL()`. See the tips section of `CASE()` in [the formula function documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Comment: Im getting a syntax error Error: Syntax error. Extra IF

Comment: if i use CASE it says Syntx ERROR "Extra Subcontractor"

Comment: It's because you closed the case with a ) then started a new statement. Try commenting out some of the lower lines and get one line to compile and then add lines one at a time.

Comment: When i do this it says Extra "Subcontractor

Comment: What do you have right now?

Comment: let's go to chat as comments are getting long. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57071/formula-not-working

Comment: dont have a 20 reputation

Comment: Bummer. Edit the question then.